# Autoregressive moving average (ARMA) model in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, statistics

Is there a way to implement an [autoregressive moving average (ARMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model) model in GEE? For example, for MODIS NDVI dataset spanning 1 year:

```
var modisNDVIcoll = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A2"); 
var modisNDVIcoll = modisNDVIcoll.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2009, null, 'year'));
```